# How many numbers of 7 digits greater than 3500000 can be formed using the digits 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

My approach to solve this questions has been dividing the problem in 2 parts.

First Part.

The numbers that started with 37, since 22, 33, 31, etc. are not really options. So in the first two places I only have 1 possibility (37), leaving 1,2,2,3,3,7 available. So the numbers of combinations for this are:

$1\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1=240$

Second Part.

The numbers that started with 7, leaving 1,2,2,3,3,3 available. So, the number of combinations for this are:

$1\times6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1=720$

Therefore the numbers than can be formed are: $240+720=960$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the first part, you must have $1,2,2,3,3$.

Comment: Nice start, but the way you are counting, rearranging the two $2$'s would count differently in your total.

Comment: how would you count for $1,2,2$? by your method: $3\cdot 2\cdot 1=6$, whereas it must be $\frac{3!}{2!}=3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get rid of multiplicity as some digits are not distinguishable.

For the first case, choosing from $1,2,2,3,3$ should be

$$\frac{5!}{2!2!}$$

For the second case, choosing from $1,2,2,3,3,3$ should be

$$\frac{6!}{2!3!}$$

$$\frac{5!}{2!2!}+\frac{6!}{2!3!}=\frac{5!}{2!2!}\left(1+ \frac{6}{3}\right)=\frac{360}{4}=90$$

Comment: I was thinking about that, thank you for your answer and confirmation.